# Using Azure Storage Account Table as External table in Azure SQL databse

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

I have a storage account (StorageV2), there is a table. I would like to be able select from this table from Azure SQL database:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE testtable
WITH (LOCATION = 'https://<MyStorageAccount>.table.core.windows.net/test',
    CREDENTIAL = testtable,
    TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE
);

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE testtable (
    PartitionKey varchar(1000),
    RowKey varchar(1000),
    Content varchar(max)
)
WITH (
        DATA_SOURCE = testtable
    )
;
```

If it's not possible to connect as an external table, are there any other options to connect to a table in a storage account using database tools? Without datafactory, databrix, SSIS,...

> Msg 46525, Level 16, State 31, Line 23
> External tables are not supported with the provided data source type.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current&preserve-view=true&tabs=dedicated#type---blob_storage--rdbms--shard_map_manager) explicitly covers this: *"`TYPE` = `BLOB_STORAGE` is only permitted for bulk operations; you cannot create external tables for an external data source with `TYPE` = `BLOB_STORAGE`."*

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Database supports OPENROWSET and BULK INSERT with Azure Blob Storage files.

[Examples of bulk access to data in Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-access-to-data-in-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-ver16)

So you can create a view that uses OPENROWSET over an Azure blob instead of an external table.
Eg

```
create or alter view my MyAzureInvoices
as
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'week3/inv-2017-01-19.csv',
   DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureInvoices',
   FORMAT = 'CSV',
   FORMATFILE='invoices.fmt',
   FORMATFILE_DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureInvoices'
   ) AS DataFile;
```

Comment: «The BULK INSERT and OPENROWSET statements can directly access a file» - I would like to work with a table, not a file

Comment: Use a view or load a table from the file.

Comment: Could you please give more details about a view? I have a sets of different files (excel, csv) with various structures. I am going to parse files and store data into one table in blob storage. After that, use sql procedures for updating data marts using data from blob storage